# Ruby on Rails localization resource with translation and nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization, rails-i18n

What I'm trying to achieve has the following idea:

```
en:
  product:
     category: "Product category"
     category: 
       product: "Product"
```

So that I would get following results

```
t("product.category") => "Product category"
t("product.category.product") => "Product"
```

However the latter category overwrites the first category, so I'm getting like this:

```
t("product.category") => ":product: Product"
t("product.category.product") => "Product"
```

Any way to achieve that kind of translation structure that returns the text if asked for the root, or is the Rails translations structured so that it's either a String (translation) or a Hash (nested translations) and there is no way to have "both"?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try it in Rails way?

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      product: Product
      category: Category
    attributes:
      product:
        category: Product category
      category:
        product: Product
```

Next you can use methods:
`Model.model_name.human` to show model name
or
`Model.human_attribute_name(attribute)` to show attribute name

More information here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: I'm getting those translation String constants from another backend server and I can't really change them as they are used elsewhere as well.

Comment: You have the wrong file YAML. If you read this file using `YAML::load`, you will get `{"en"=>{"product"=>{"category"=>{"product"=>"Product"}}}}`. 
You lost information that `category: "Product category"`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML